# backtype.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I am trying to submit a topology to my STORM cluster and I am getting the following error on running mvn package

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building storm-starter 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ storm-starter ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 4 resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ storm-starter ---
    [INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /Users/sharath/workspace/storm/target/classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] /Users/sharath/workspace/storm/src/jvm/storm/starter/CustomToplogy.java:[41,35] unreported exception backtype.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [INFO] 1 error
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.396 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-19T20:35:37+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/81M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project storm-starter: Compilation failure
    [ERROR] /Users/sharath/workspace/storm/src/jvm/storm/starter/CustomToplogy.java:[41,35] unreported exception backtype.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I did some research and found out that the error occurs if a topology with the same name already exists on the cluster. But I queried STORM and found that no such topology exists.

Can someone help me understand what is going on?
The code for the topology is below..

```
package storm.starter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import storm.starter.spout.Spout;

import storm.starter.bolt.RedisBolt;
import java.util.*;

import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;

public class CustomTopology {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    //List<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String host = args[0];
    String broker = "tcp://192.168.5.102:1443";
    String client = "test_client";
    String topic = "#";
    String redis_host = "192.168.5.102:6379";
    //hosts.add(host);

    builder.setSpout(...); //Omitted for security
    builder.setBolt(...); //Omitted for security
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);
    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
      conf.setNumWorkers(3);

      StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
    }
    else {

      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("CustomT1", conf, builder.createTopology());
      Utils.sleep(10000);
      cluster.killTopology("CustomT1");
      cluster.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

I setup my storm infrastructure using https://github.com/miguno/wirbelsturm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology isn't alive, maven is throwing that error during compilation.

> unreported exception backtype.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException;
>   must be caught or declared to be thrown

This means you [must catch or specify an exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091589/java-unreported-exception).

Change this line:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
```

To this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

Comment: you can also use a catch block instead of throwing the exception .. it would allow you to gain more control in case of the same exception occurs